# Any way to use VoltDB in rails app?

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails

I've been curiously looking at VoltDB and one year ago I have even seen a gem that was providing Ruby connection to VoltDB. I have checked today again and it seems gone.

I'm planning to go through the "VoltDB University" tutorials but I would really like to know if i'm not wasting my time because it would be super hard to connect to the database if using Rails.

Does anyone have any info on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gem seems to be outdated: https://rubygems.org/gems/voltrb - mentions VoltDB v1.1, last updated in 2010. Initial repository is gone, but here is a clone: https://github.com/Cowen/VoltRb

It uses JSON API, but there is a "VoltDB Client Wire Protocol" which has a [specification](http://downloads.voltdb.com/documentation/wireprotocol.pdf), so you could try to implement a new client.

Comment: Isn't it in other words swimming against the current trying to use Rails with VoltDB?

Comment: Decision is up to you. I'm sure you're not the only one who is interested in having a Ruby client for VoltDB, and I see no reasons why it could be bad to have such a client, since there are clients for PHP and Node.js. It's just happened so there is no up-to-date Ruby client.